# Convert full words date into numbers

Tags: date, type-conversion, language-agnostic

I have a bunch of dates in a database written in full worded text and I need to convert them into a useable date field. It's a one time deal but there's a few million lines so doing it manually is unthinkable.

"January the twenty sixth, nineteen eighty nine" would become "1989/01/26"

The format isn't always he same, I could also have "The nineteenth of August, nineteen hundred ninety"

Ideally doing it in SQL would be easier, but I could run a script and update the database after.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is too specific for my case to post here, but here's a pseudo-code of what I did for the numbers so maybe someone will be saved the headache, especially with numbers in French.

```
NumberString = 'Nineteen hundred ninety nine'

-- Replace each word individually by their value : Nineteen hundred ninety nine would be 19,100,90,9 (or 10,9,100,4,20,10,9 in French)
NumberString= '19 100 90 9'    
-- For French only, replace '4 20' by 80 (easier for the next step)

Total = 0
NumberArray = NumberString.SplitOnSpaces
FOREACH Numbers as Number
  IF Number is not a power of 100 THEN Total += Number
  IF Number is a power of 100 THEN
    IF Total%Number = 0 THEN Total += Number
    ELSE 
      ModuloTemp = Total%Number
      Total -= ModuloTemp
      Total += ModuloTemp * Number
END
```

It won't work when the number is written in parts, like 2020 would be 'twenty twenty', but it was good enough for my needs.

Then for the date I just find the month's position. If it's day, month, year you can build back the date using the month as a separator.  If it's month, day, year then you have to find the ordinal number (first, second, tenth, etc.) to distinguish the year from the day.